# Press button to send email and 'disabled' the text area field

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I am using Flask for creating my webpage. I added a section "contact us" in the web and the email and everything is working ok except the part where I am trying to disable the text as soon as the user presses the send button. Right now, when the user presses the "send email" button the page star loading and finally send the email after a few seconds, which is ok. The problem is that during those few second the user still can write in the text area, what is written after pressing the button is not included in the email, but I would like that immediately after pressing the button the text area gets "disabled". I have tried this:

```
@main.route('/Contactus', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def ContactUs():
    form=ContactUsForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form.email.render_kw = {'disabled': 'disabled'}
        form.title.render_kw = {'disabled': 'disabled'}
        form.text.render_kw = {'disabled': 'disabled'}
        email = form.email.data
        subject = form.title.data
        body = form.text.data
        contat= [email,subject,body]
        contat_us(contat)
        flash(f'Thanks for your email. Soon we will contact you through your email: {form.email.data}.', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for("main.home"))
    return render_template('Contactus.html', title='Contac us', form=form)
```

I thought that the problem was that the "if" runs at once and I tried this:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
        form.email.render_kw = {'disabled': 'disabled'}
        form.title.render_kw = {'disabled': 'disabled'}
        form.text.render_kw = {'disabled': 'disabled'}
if form.validate_on_submit():
        email = form.email.data
        subject = form.title.data
        body = form.text.data
        contat= [email,subject,body]
        contat_us(contat)
        flash(f'Thanks for your email. Soon we will contact you through your email: {form.email.data}.', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for("main.home"))
```

but still is not working. Is there a way to make the lines that disabled the text run before the rest of the lines after pressing the "send button"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript in your webpage to disable the text-area and the button as soon as you click on it. (Using something like JQuery could be easier to write)

Also, sending mail in the main event loop is not good from UX point of view. You can use something like celery or threads to send the mail asynchronously.

Comment: By "asynchronously" do you mean a different function? something like this?
`def sendemail(contat): 
 contat_us(contat)`

Comment: Yes, the function should be called from a thread. (See "Asynchronous Email" heading in https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-x-email-support)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am going to try the instructions from that blog. I imagine that if I am calling another function the "if" of my code is going to end the prosses, therefore the text area will be disabled before sending the email. is that correct?

Comment: Segregate the GET & POST request in your function (`if request.method == 'POST':`) and return the appropriate parameters like disabled etc.

Comment: Hi again, the way `if request.method == 'POST':` did not work, I tested before. I do not know if the `POST` check and the `validate_on_submit` check run at the same time, but finally, I have the same problem. The solution in the blog (link) does work perfectly; however in the way that I am configuring my Flask-app does not allow me to just call the 'app' as suggested in the blog (`args=(app,msg)`).